# ActiveMQ Artemis http and https in bootstrap.xml

Tags: jetty, activemq-artemis

I hope you have an idea.

I am working with an ActiveMQ Artemis Broker and installed a metrics plugin to use with prometheus and grafana (https://github.com/rh-messaging/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin/). Like the instruction says, I added `<app url="metrics" war="metrics.war"/>` to the bootstrap.xml

We're working with a vendor providing us with the Grafana dashboards as long as we are providing metrics they can work with. The problem is that the vendor wants to access the metrics page (https://activemq:port/metrics) via HTTP and not HTTPS, which is configured in the bootstrap.xml ( `<web bind="https://0.0.0.0:port" path="web" keyStorePath=...`) Their effort would be disproportionately high to change their system to work with HTTPS now.

Is it possible to configure the jetty-Webserver to serve the console etc. via HTTPS and the URL activemq:port/metrics via HTTP?

I tried to add another web-container in the bootstrap.xml, now binding `bind="http://0.0.0.0:port/"` and adding the metrics plugin in it but the webserver wasn't happy with two web-containers :/

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible. However, the project could be enhanced to support multiple `web` instances in `bootstrap.xml`. Contributions are always welcome.

Comment: Alright thank you for the quick answer. Damn, I thought so. Gonna speak with the vendor about it. Sorry, I am just a simple Sysadmin, no Java experience at all on my side D: